# How to get crypto currency wallet balances

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, c

I am trying to build an app that will pull in all my wallet balances. I can easily do this with exchange apis, but how do I get balances that are stored in wallet?

Do I need to set up bitcoind, litecoind, neo equivalent, and all of the rest? That sounds like a lot of work and A LOT of server space / resources?

I'm surprised I haven't been able to find a single unified api provider, where I can just send a BTC address, or a LTC address or a NEO address and it returns me a balance. Does such a thing not exist?

Thanks :)

Comment: Questions seeking product or service reviews are off-topic because they tend to attract subjective, low-quality, and spam answers.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to set up bitcoind, litecoind, neo equivalent, and all of the rest?

You don't have to; you can use different APIs for different coins. But not all coins will have a service that offers that, so for those you will need to run your own node software.

> I'm surprised I haven't been able to find a single unified api provider

You've answered this yourself:

> That sounds like a lot of work and A LOT of server space / resources?

It's simply too expensive for someone to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You cant get balance of a address, a address is not a account or wallet and accounts dont exist in bitcoin anymore all address's are unchangeable linked to account " " you could get the balance of your wallet in its entirety but not "address's". A address is simply a entry point into your wallet, the best you can do is get "getreceivedbyaddress" but this would not show you the balance only a starting point.